# Seeking NRCS soil survey data at state or county scale?

Tags: data, united-states, soil

Ideally, I would like to download all the NRCS's soil survey data for Pennsylvania, as is shown on Web Soil Survey.  However, if it's not possible, I would like to at least get the data for Bradford County.  With Web Soil Survey, AOIs are limited to 100,000 acres.

Is there a source where I can download larger AOIs?

I would be interested in any other soils datasets if you have them.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

Due to some current hardware issues (I work for NRCS), all features of the Geospatial Datagateway may not work. https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/soils is a direct link to all downloadable soil products.

Information on products available from the agency's Soil Survey Division can be found at https://websoilsurvey.sc.egov.usda.gov/App/HomePage.htm

Answer (score 2):

Available for download by county here:
https://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/GDGOrder.aspx

If you want to use the data to it's full potential, use the soil data viewer, too:
https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/wps/portal/nrcs/detail/soils/survey/geo/?cid=nrcseprd337066